# Sci-fi movie featuring a fat man running sideways on a wall

Tags: story-identification, movie, super-hero

This is clearly a fairly recent sci-fi movie featuring superpowers, but I don't recall seeing it advertised.  There's an obese man with his belly hanging out, running on the *side* of a skyscraper roughly thirty feet above a busy street, clutching a package.  His sideways gravity does not affect the vehicles or pedestrians on the street below/to his right.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: A sideways shot of fat man running along the side of a tall building in a city with a road visible below him]

I found this in a YouTube video that contained a number of sci-fi clips, all unattributed.  Most of them I recognized.

Comment: Do you have a link to the video? Please put it here.

Comment: Not any longer, unfortunately

Comment: Are there any more details you know? Do you think it was Marvel or DC?

Comment: It's not really sci-fi but more horror/fantasy

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The movie is [*R.I.P.D.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R.I.P.D.) (2013).

The scene in the screenshot: